# Программно отключить сетевой адаптер

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите как в [c#] программно отключить устройство

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

от сети?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Включение/Отключение сетевых адаптеров средствами WMI

(CSWMIEnableDisableNetworkAdapter)
(Пример разработан и проверен для VS2010)

1. Конструктор NetworkAdapter class

```
internal class NetworkAdapter 
{ 
    #region NetworkAdapter Properties 
 
 
    /// <summary> 
    /// The DeviceId of the NetworkAdapter 
    /// </summary> 
    public int DeviceId 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    } 
     
    /// <summary> 
    /// The ProductName of the NetworkAdapter 
    /// </summary> 
    public string Name 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    } 
 
 
    /// <summary> 
    /// The NetEnabled status of the NetworkAdapter 
    /// </summary> 
    public int NetEnabled 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    } 
 
 
    /// <summary> 
    /// The Net Connection Status Value 
    /// </summary> 
    public int NetConnectionStatus 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    } 
 
 
    /// <summary> 
    /// The Net Connection Status Description 
    /// </summary> 
    public static string[] SaNetConnectionStatus =  
    {  
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus0, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus1, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus2, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus3, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus4, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus5, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus6, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus7, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus8, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus9, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus10, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus11, 
        Resources.NetConnectionStatus12 
    }; 
 
 
    /// <summary> 
    /// Enum the NetEnabled Status 
    /// </summary> 
    private enum EnumNetEnabledStatus 
    {  
        Disabled = -1, 
        Unknow, 
        Enabled 
    } 
 
 
    /// <summary> 
    /// Enum the Operation reuslt of Enable and Disable  Network Adapter 
    /// </summary> 
    private enum EnumEnableDisableResult 
    { 
        Fail = -1, 
        Unknow, 
        Success 
    } 
 
 
    #endregion 
 
 
    #region Construct NetworkAdapter 
 
 
    public NetworkAdapter(int deviceId, 
        string name,   
        int netEnabled,  
        int netConnectionStatus) 
    { 
        DeviceId = deviceId; 
        Name = name; 
        NetEnabled = netEnabled; 
        NetConnectionStatus = netConnectionStatus; 
    } 
}
```

2.  Этот код находит все адаптеры.

```
List<NetworkAdapter> allNetworkAdapter = new List<NetworkAdapter>(); 
 
 
string strWQuery = "SELECT DeviceID, ProductName, Description, "  
    + "NetEnabled, NetConnectionStatus " 
    + "FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter "  
    + "WHERE Manufacturer <> 'Microsoft' "; 
ObjectQuery oQuery = new System.Management.ObjectQuery(strWQuery); 
ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oQuery); 
ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get(); 
 
 
foreach (ManagementObject mo in oReturnCollection) 
{ 
    netEnabled = (Convert.ToBoolean(mo["NetEnabled"].ToString())) ? 1 : -1; 
    allNetworkAdapter.Add(new NetworkAdapter( 
        Convert.ToInt32(mo["DeviceID"].ToString()),  
        mo["ProductName"].ToString(), 
        mo["Description"].ToString(),  
        netEnabled,  
        Convert.ToInt32(mo["NetConnectionStatus"].ToString()))); 
}; 
return allNetworkAdapter;
```

3.      Этот код включает и выключает сетевой адаптер.

```
ManagementObject currentMObject = new ManagementObject(); 
string strWQuery = "SELECT DeviceID,ProductName,Description,NetEnabled " 
    + "FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter "  
    + "WHERE DeviceID = " + this.DeviceID.ToString(); 
ObjectQuery oQuery = new System.Management.ObjectQuery(strWQuery); 
ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oQuery); 
ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get(); 
 
 
foreach (ManagementObject mo in oReturnCollection) 
{ 
    currentMObject = mo; 
} 
 
 
//Enable the Network Adapter 
currentMObject.InvokeMethod("Enable", null); 
 
 
//Disable the Network Adapter 
//currentMObject.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
```

[Оригинальная статья](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Disableenable-network-8112f642)

[Ресурс на MSDN(описание класса Win32_NetworkAdapter class)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx)