# Выключить сетевой адаптер от сети

Tags: c#, wmi

Имеется имя адаптера: `TAP-Win32 Adapter V9` ( к примеру )

Нашёл пример ([Программно отключить сетевой адаптер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728743/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)) - Но очень сложно.

Хочу сделать в консоли вписать нужный мне адаптер и отключить его.

Перепробовал пару вариантов, но ни один из них не работал :(

[NetworkAdaptersUtility](https://gist.github.com/tommyready/df468fb96667fea3862e387656198c58)

[CSWMIEnableDisableNetworkAdapter](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Disableenable-network-8112f642)  - Пример работает только он на WinForms

У меня есть код который  включает и выключает сетевой адаптер.

```
ManagementObject currentMObject = new ManagementObject(); 
string strWQuery = "SELECT DeviceID,ProductName,Description,NetEnabled " 
    + "FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter "  
    + "WHERE DeviceID = " + this.DeviceID.ToString(); 
ObjectQuery oQuery = new System.Management.ObjectQuery(strWQuery); 
ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oQuery); 
ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get(); 

foreach (ManagementObject mo in oReturnCollection) 
{ 
    currentMObject = mo; 
} 

currentMObject.InvokeMethod("Enable", null); //Включает сетевой адаптер
currentMObject.InvokeMethod("Disable", null); //Выключает сетевой адаптер
```

**Пишу в консольном приложение C#**

Как мне имея имя адаптера отключить его ?

Попробовал сделать так ( работает только отключение, а включение не работает )

```
 /*Функция для выключения адаптера*/
private static bool DisableNetWork(ManagementObject network)
{
   try
   {
     network.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
     return true;
   }
   catch
   {
     return false;
   }
}

 /*Функция для включения адаптера*/
private static bool EnableNetWork(ManagementObject network)
{
  try
  {
    network.InvokeMethod("Enable", null);
    return true;
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }
}

private static void RestartNetWork()
{
  string manage = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter";
  var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(manage);
  var collection = searcher.Get();

  foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
  {
     if (obj["Name"].ToString() == "TAP-Win32 Adapter V9")
     {
        Console.WriteLine(obj["Name"].ToString() + "\n");

        DisableNetWork(obj); // Функция срабатывает! 
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        EnableNetWork(obj); // Функция не срабатывает!

        return;
     }
  }
}
```

Немного изменил метод **RestartNetWork**

```
private static void RestartNetWork(bool enable)
{
  uint retRslt = 1;
  string manage = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter";
  using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(manage))
  {
      foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
      {
       if (obj["Name"].ToString() == "TAP-Win32 Adapter V9")
       {
          retRslt = (uint)(enable ? obj.InvokeMethod("Enable", null) : obj.InvokeMethod("Disable", null));
          Console.WriteLine($"{obj["Name"].ToString()} Disabled");
       }
      }
   }
}
```

И по прежнему функция включения адаптера не работает. Буду искать причину.
Есть подозрение что после отключения адаптера, он не видит в `if (obj["Name"].ToString() == "TAP-Win32 Adapter V9")` Имя адаптера, и поэтому не может включиться. Но и создав новый метод с проходом цикла и включение не дал результата. Что делать подскажите ?