# Сетевой адаптер Hamachi

Tags: c#, wpf, веб-программирование, запрос

Всем привет, прошу помощи, проблема странная(все говорят проверять конфигурацию пк/роутер/провайдера, но в то же время она спокойно воспроизвелась на двух других пк в сетях других провайдеров)

Такое дело:
пишу на c# wpf, юзаю для запросов к сайтам как WebClient, так и HttpWebRequest
так же  временами играю по hamachi, который по хозяйски установил свой виртуальный сетевой адаптер

[image: вот он]

так вот, пока сетевой адаптер hamachi работает, запросы загрузки html-кода и 16х16 картинки идут по 30-40 секунд, а то и
вообще выпадают в ексепшн(абослютно рандомно), но стоит отрубить адаптер hamachi, как сразу всё работает отлично, 
вот только он назад включаеться

код из этой темы [Программно отключить сетевой адаптер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728743/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)
работает(видит адаптеры), но не отключает адаптер

если кто знает, как заставить hamachi включать адаптер только когда нужно(в автозапуске его уже нет)/программно заставить запрос пойти по нужному адаптеру(прокси WebClient уже менял)/программно вырубить хотя бы ненадолго этот адаптер/любой другой способ - прошу помощи и буду сильно благодарен

Comment: как по мне, я немного непонятно выразился в предыдущем вопросе, посему он просто утонул

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, так что оставлю решение тут, может кому надо будет

```
public static void DisableAdapter(string interfaceName)
    {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface set interface \"" + interfaceName + "\" disable");
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.UseShellExecute = true; 
            psi.Verb = "runas";
            p.StartInfo = psi;
            p.Start();
    }
```

Вот метод
а вот так вызвал перед отправкой запроса

```
DisableAdapter("Hamachi");
```

это отправит хамачи в нокаут на пару секунд, чтоб запрос успел пролететь